# Closing tag img error in itext xmlworker. Expected closing tag img error in itext xmlworker

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, itext

I really need your help! I know this question was asked couple times, but I don't see any answer... So, when I try to convert a div tag that contains img tag, I get an exception -

> Invalid nested tag div found, expected closing tag img

My html is

```
 <div id = "Grid">
      <img src="img/q12.gif" />
 </div>
```

my vb.net code is

```
    Dim sr As New StringReader(Request.Form(hfGridHtml.UniqueID))
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F)
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New 
      FileStream(Context.Server.MapPath("~/out.pdf"), FileMode.CreateNew))
    pdfDoc.Open()
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:61834/ejik.pdf")
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.End()
```

and my JS is

```
 $(function () {
    $("[id*=btnExport]").click(function () {
        $("[id*=hfGridHtml]").val($("#Grid").html());
    });
});
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Is the whole source HTML definitely well-formed XHTML?

Comment: yes, it is, just doublechecked

Comment: Is there a stack trace on the exception?  If so, does it specify the line number that throws the exception?

Comment: Line 27:         Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(Context.Server.MapPath("~/out.pdf"), FileMode.CreateNew))
Line 28:         pdfDoc.Open()
Line 29:         XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)
Line 30:         pdfDoc.Close()
Line 31:         Response.Redirect("http://localhost:61834/out.pdf")

Comment: Which of those throws the Invalid-nested-tag exception? Line 29?

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to mention. Yes, line #29

Comment: So, in the HTML, above those three lines that you quoted, there's no other `img` tags that lack the closing tag (e.g. `<img></img>`) or fail to self-close (e.g. `<img />`)?

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

Comment: Try adding a closing tag to `img`, rather than having it be self-closed, and see if that works.  If not, try removing the closing of the `img` tag entirely.

Comment: Also, just to be sure... there's no more `div` tags after this one which might be what it's complaining about, right?  This is the only one?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem ...

Comment: Yes, this is the only one... When I replace img tag with p tag, it works properly

Comment: Actually, I found this problem with all self-closing tags. For example when I add hr tag instead of img tag, I have the same problem

Comment: Upgrade to iText 7 + pdfHTML. The version you are using is being abandoned. See the [HTML to PDF](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) and you'll understand that all the problems you're experiencing have been fixed. There's no valid reason not to upgrade, is there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will face the same problem. I found what was the reason. When I do $("[id*=hfGridHtml]").val($("#Grid").html()); it returns the img tag without closing "/". I am sure there is some proper solution, but I just add the closing tag "/" and it works!